# How can I get JasperViewer to prioritize save option to PDF

Tags: java, swing, reflection, jasper-reports

I have an implementation where `JasperViewer` is used to preview and save reports. The first saving format offered by the viewer is `.jrprint` and I'm trying to change that to `pdf`. I'm employing the following method to help me with that

```
private static void promotePdfSaveFormat(JasperViewer jasperViewer) {
    /* get via reflection (with jOOR) the parameter JasperViewer object's member viewer (of type JRViewer) */
    JRViewer viewer = on(jasperViewer).call("viewer").get();
    /* get via reflection JRViewer object's member tlbToolBar (of type JRViewerToolbar) */
    JRViewerToolbar tlbToolBar = on(viewer).call("tlbToolBar").get();
    /* call tlbToolBar's getSaveContributors() */
    Arrays.stream(tlbToolBar.getSaveContributors()).forEach(
        e -> {
            /* Find the one that is of type JRPdfSaveContributor (using instanceof) */
            if (e instanceof JRPdfSaveContributor){
                /* set JRViewerToolbar object member lastSaveContributor value to the instance of JRPdfSaveContributor */
                on(tlbToolBar).call("lastSaveContributor").get();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Everytime a new Object is created inside the class like `JasperViewer viewer = new JasperViewer(...)`, I'm adding `promotePdfSaveFormat(viewer)` immediately after it. When I run the app, I get an error at `JRViewer viewer = on(jasperViewer).call("viewer").get();`

The error is as follows

```
org.joor.ReflectException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No similar method viewer with params [] could be found on type class net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer.
```

Comment: You can override `JRViewerToolbar` class and set `JRSaveContributor lastSaveContributor` field with`net.sf.jasperreports.view.save.JRPdfSaveContributor` value at constructor, for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a thorough inspection, I realized that I was making a really stupid mistake. It was bound to throw `NoSuchMethodException` because the following lines are trying to access a `method` and not a `field`.

```
JRViewer viewer = on(jasperViewer).call("viewer").get();
JRViewerToolbar tlbToolBar = on(viewer).call("tlbToolBar").get();
```

Then, I modified my method, to access `field`. The entire method looks like this now:

```
private static void promotePdfSaveFormat(JasperViewer jasperViewer) {
    /* get via reflection the parameter JasperViewer object's member viewer (of type JRViewer) */
    JRViewer viewer = on(jasperViewer).field("viewer").get();
    /* get via reflection JRViewer object's member tlbToolBar (of type JRViewerToolbar) */
    JRViewerToolbar tlbToolBar = on(viewer).field("tlbToolBar").get();
    /* call tlbToolBar's getSaveContributors() */
    Arrays.stream(tlbToolBar.getSaveContributors())
        /* filter instance of type JRPdfSaveContributor */
        .filter(e -> e instanceof JRPdfSaveContributor)
        /* set JRViewerToolbar object member lastSaveContributor value to the instance of JRPdfSaveContributor */
        .forEach(e -> on(tlbToolBar).set("lastSaveContributor", e));
}
```

Now, `JasperViewer` shows `PDF` as the first saving option.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

They are called [JRSaveContributor](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/view/JRSaveContributor.html).

You can set your own [`JRViewer.setSaveContributors`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/view/JRViewer.html#setSaveContributors-net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRSaveContributor:A-) or an easy way to reorder (remove) is to get the ones that are instanced and then loop them checking the description to see what you like to keep/reorder and then set them back to the `JasperViewer`.

**Quick Example**, setting pdf first.

```
final JRViewer jrv = new JRViewer(report);
JRSaveContributor[] sv = jrv.getSaveContributors();
List<JRSaveContributor> reorded = new ArrayList<JRSaveContributor>();
for (JRSaveContributor s : sv) {
    if (s.getDescription().contains(".pdf")){
        reorded.add(0,s);
    }else{
        reorded.add(s);
    }
}
jrv.setSaveContributors((JRSaveContributor[]) reorded.toArray(new JRSaveContributor[reorded.size()]));
```

> You may also just like to skip `.jrprint`? if you are using java8 this code can be improved using streams, I leave that exercise to reader.

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but in my case, `getSaveContributors()` is inside `JRViewerToolbar` and not `JRViewer`. I also need to set it to `pdf` during runtime. I'm still getting `NoSuchMethodException`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not require the reflection to access private/protected fields.  It is obviously derived from both @PetterFriberg and @RoshanUpreti's solutions.  It involves subclassing `JRViewer`.

```
public static final class PdfFirstJRViewer
    extends JRViewer
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public PdfFirstJRViewer(JasperPrint print)
    {
        super(print);

        movePdfToTop();
    }

    public void movePdfToTop()
    {
        JRSaveContributor[] sv = tlbToolBar.getSaveContributors();
        List<JRSaveContributor> reorded = new ArrayList<>();
        for (JRSaveContributor s : sv)
        {
            if (s.getDescription().contains(".pdf"))
            {
                reorded.add(0, s);
            }
            else
            {
                reorded.add(s);
            }
        }
        tlbToolBar.setSaveContributors(
            reorded.toArray(new JRSaveContributor[reorded.size()]));
    }
}
```

You may need to override additional constructors to get the behavior you want.